# How to change data type for column on partioned external Hive table (parquet) without deleting data?

Tags: hadoop, hive, parquet

I have a partitioned external Hive table. It has data loaded from parquet files. I have a few columns in that table that require a datatype change (TIMESTAMP -> STRING). Currently, when you query these columns, it returns NULL values because of the wrong data-type.

I ran `ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE col_1 col_1 STRING;` to successfully change the datatype for that column to STRING, but when I query the table again, the data in that table is still showing NULL. Is there a way to update the data without dropping the partitions and re-loading the data from scratch?

Comment: how did your loaded the data and why originally there are nulls? Please describe in details. If you loaded using insert and timestamps failed to convert from strings then for sure now there are NULLs in data files, nothing will help except re-loading

Comment: @leftjoin They are not originally NULL. The raw data has correct data. The issue is the data type for the column is wrong. Therefore it is showing NULL.

Comment: The table is stored as parquet now, right?. May I ask how did you check that it contains not NULLs? Also how did you loaded it is still not clear? please provide more details